# What is a better way to create a new variable compared to `ifelse` in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

I am working with:
- panel data set
- 10 time periods

I need to create a dummy variable, `RL` that is equal to `1 (TRUE)` forever if the dummy variable `RS` has been `1` once.

in other words:
The new variable `RL` (spanning 10 periods) has to be `1` in t and all subsequent periods if `RS` was `1` in period t-1. If no `TRUE` has happened in `RS` and `RS` is `0 (FALSE)` then `RL` should also be 0.

As soon as `TRUE` happens in `RS` in period t then `RL` has to be `1` onwards (in t+1, t+2, t+3, t+4 ..., t+end of panel).

My problem is that `FALSE` is not properly read as `0` but just as `NA`.

I used `ifelse` but it gives me way too many blanks:

```
    df$r_1RL  <- rep(0,nrow(df)) # is = 0 cause noone can retire in t-1 since "RS0" doesn't exists
    df$r_2RL  <- ifelse(  df$r_1RS == 1, 1, ifelse(df$r_1RS == 0, 0, NA))
    df$r_3RL  <- ifelse( (df$r_1RS == 1 | df$r_2RS == 1), 1, ifelse( (df$r_1RS == 0 | df$r_2RS == 0), 0, NA))
    df$r_4RL  <- ifelse( (df$r_1RS == 1 | df$r_2RS == 1 | df$r_3RS == 1), 1, ifelse( (df$r_1RS == 0 | df$r_2RS == 0 | df$r_3RS == 0), 0, NA)) 
    df$r_5RL  <- ifelse( (df$r_1RS == 1 | df$r_2RS == 1 | df$r_3RS == 1 | df$r_4RS == 1 ), 1, ifelse( (df$r_1RS == 0 | df$r_2RS == 0 | df$r_3RS == 0 | df$r_4RS == 0), 0, NA))
    and so on... up to 10RL


   df <- structure(list(r_1RS = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA
    ), r_2RS = c(FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA), r_3RS = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA), r_4RS = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, NA, FALSE), r_5RS = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE
    ), r_6RS = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, TRUE), r_7RS = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE), r_8RS = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), r_9RS = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE), r_10RS = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, NA, FALSE), r_1RL = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), r_2RL = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), r_3RL = c(0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, NA), r_4RL = c(0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA), r_5RL = c(0, NA, 
    0, 0, NA, NA), r_6RL = c(0, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA), r_7RL = c(0, 1, 
    0, 0, NA, 1), r_8RL = c(0, 1, 0, 0, NA, 1), r_9RL = c(1, 1, 0, 
    0, NA, 1), r_10RL = c(1, 1, 0, 0, NA, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here you can see how as soon as true happens in `RS`, `RL` is `1` after. But there are two problems.. first of all the `1` in r_10RL should be a `NA` and r_7RL should have `0`'s and **not** `NA's`

[image]

The red circled `NA` should be 0 and the yellow circled `1` should be `NA`

Comment: You mean like cumsum(RS) > 0?

Comment: Im adding a picture to show what I want, even though it is not good conduct. But I have trouble explaining my problem

Comment: Hello Emil, i think it would help if you could add a little example of your dataframe df and also an example for the desired output

Comment: I dont know how to recreate this dataframe. I posted a picture however

Comment: use `dput(df)` and copy paste the output in your question

Comment: My console cannot contain all of the numbers, only when I use `head`. Is there a fix? I would love to send the whole dataframe

Comment: First, `head` is enough. Second, I dont understand what your `df` means. In your question it looks like you have a time variable, where is it? Wht so many columns? What do they mean?

Comment: Also, your RL variables have `NA`'s in them. `NA` are not 1 nor 0. Run `NA == 1` or `NA == 0` in your console to see the result.

Comment: When paneldata is in wide-format as it is in my example, you don't use a time variable. It is in the column names r_1, r_2, ... , r_10. See?
Also I know that NA is not 1 or 0. What the columns mean are not really important to my question, I am simply asking how to construct one dummy variable using only ONE other variable - so you don't need to think about the other 331 variables in my data set. 

What I need to do is to construct a variable, RL, that is 1, when RS has been 1 in an earlier period. If RS has not yet been 1, then RL should be 0 (or NA if there exists no observations in RS)

Answer (score 1):

This feels very hackish, and I do not love it, but it works on your sample data. You could probably take the general idea and make it more efficient. Let me know if you run into any issues!

```
# Using the first 10 columns of your dput dataframe
df <- df[1:10]
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  r_1RS r_2RS r_3RS r_4RS r_5RS r_6RS r_7RS r_8RS r_9RS r_10RS
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> 
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE 
2 FALSE NA    FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
5 FALSE FALSE FALSE NA    NA    NA    NA    FALSE FALSE NA    
6 NA    NA    NA    FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 

# Createing a copy for the new columns
df2 <- df

# There may be other ways to handle NA's but you mentioend you want them
# as zero so this should work for you
df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0

# Changing all values after TRUE to 1
df2 <- data.frame(t(apply(df2, 1, function(x) as.numeric(cumsum(x) > 0))))

# Chaning the names
names(df2) <- sub("RS", "RL", names(df), fixed = T)

# Combining the columns
> cbind(df, df2)
  r_1RS r_2RS r_3RS r_4RS r_5RS r_6RS r_7RS r_8RS r_9RS r_10RS r_1RL r_2RL r_3RL r_4RL r_5RL r_6RL r_7RL r_8RL r_9RL r_10RL
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1      1
2 FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1      1
3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      1
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
5 FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE FALSE     NA     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
6    NA    NA    NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1      1
```

EDIT:
Just read the last lines of your post. If you want to retain NA's in the new columns just put `df2[is.na(df)] <- NA` before `cbind`. I am a little unclear exactly what you want, so if that is not what you are looking for, can you posted a dataframe with your desired output for the sample data? Comment or post an update if you run into other issues!

EDIT2:
Another way to do the step involving `apply` (which can be slow). I could not test which way was faster so I wanted to include both:

```
# Changing all values after TRUE to 1
df2[] <- lapply(df2, as.numeric)
df2_t <- data.frame(t(df2))
> data.frame(t(cumsum(df2_t) > 0)*1)
   r_1RS r_2RS r_3RS r_4RS r_5RS r_6RS r_7RS r_8RS r_9RS r_10RS
X1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1      1
X2     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1      1
X3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      1
X4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
X5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
X6     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1      1
```